# Where can I find the Python executable that PyCharm uses in its venv?

Tags: linux-mint, python, virtualenv

I'm using PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Community Edition) under Linux Mint 20.3. I created a new project and selected "New environment using Virtualenv" as an option. PyCharm shows "Python 3.10" as the interpreter for this project:

[image: PyCharm Python Interpreters]

Running my code in this project including installing new packages into the venv all works fine. The interactive Python Console in PyCharm also confirms that Python 3.10 is being used with the executable in the venv:

[image: PyCharm Python Console]

However, now I want to execute my code from my regular terminal (without PyCharm). So I `cd` into my project directory and called the following:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ which python
python not found
```

It does not find the python executable! The 3 symlinks in `venv/bin` are all invalid (red in my terminal window):

```
(venv) $ ls -lah venv/bin/pyt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 (redacted) (redacted) 19 Mar 15 09:56 venv/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 (redacted) (redacted)  6 Mar 15 09:56 venv/bin/python3 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 (redacted) (redacted)  6 Mar 15 09:56 venv/bin/python3.10 -> python
```

There is no `/usr/bin/python3.10` installed on my system:

```
$ ls -lah /usr/bin/pyt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug  8  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3,5M Jul  1  2022 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug  8  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5,3M Nov 14 13:59 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Nov 14 13:59 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
```

So where is the Python 3.10 executable located that PyCharm uses? And how can I used the venv outside of PyCharm?

Comment: Go to settings, project, and interpreter: you will see on top your actual interpreter and you should see also the PATH of it. Or print `sys.executable`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi First screenshot is the interpreter in the settings, it points to the symlink in venv/bin. I did check sys.executable (see second screenshot), it also points to the symlink. It's just that this link doesn't point anywhere outside of PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what's going on. I had installed PyCharm via the Linux Mint Software Manager, which installs it as a **Flatpak** package. Apparently, this package uses its own Python 3.10 in the sandbox:

> **Sandboxes**
>
> With Flatpak, each application is built and run in an isolated environment, which is called the ‘sandbox’. Each sandbox contains an application and its runtime.

<sup>([Flatpak - Basic Concepts](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/basic-concepts.html#sandboxes))</sup>

When entering this sandbox, the correct Python executable is found, the venv can be entered correctly and the app can be started:

```
$ flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=bash com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community

$ ls -lah /usr/bin/pyt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody    7 Feb 27 11:05 /usr/bin/python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody   10 Feb 27 11:05 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody  16K Feb 27 11:04 /usr/bin/python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 2 nfsnobody nfsnobody 3,3K Feb 27 11:04 /usr/bin/python3.10-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody   17 Feb 27 11:05 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.10-config
$ cd <project_directory>
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ which python
<project_directory>/venv/bin/python
```